# Network Connectivity problem in 12.04LTS installed on VMWare 10.0

Tags: 12.04, networking, internet, vmware

I installed Ubuntu 12.04LTS on Virtual Machines 10.0. My Host Operating System is Windows 8.1. My Laptop Hardware configuration is Intel 4th Generation i7 with 8GB RAM with an additional 2GB nvidia Graphic card. I have an internet connection with 20Mbps which is working with all other Operating systems which I already using in Virtual Machines 10.0 except with this newly installed Ubuntu 12.04LTS. In Virtual Machine settings the Network adopter is set to Host-only. Can any one help me in resolving this problem? Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

choose an option of NAT which makes us connect to
 the host IP address in Network Adopter settings of VMWare for the corresponding operating system.